# Linq query with cartesian (wanted) and min/max in where clause

Tags: linq, aggregate

I'm trying to create a Linq instance of a stored procedure and a portion of it is giving me fits.

Here's the SQL I'm trying to emulate:

```
DECLARE @LookBack = 12,
        @FromDate = GETDATE(),
        @BEGINDATE DATETIME,
        @ENDDATE DATETIME

SELECT  @BEGINDATE = new DateTime(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(lookBack * -1),
        @ENDDATE = new DateTime(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, fromDate.Day)

DECLARE @BASEINFO TABLE( 
    IDBASEINFO INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
    IDACCOUNT INT NOT NULL,         
    BEGINDATE SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL, 
    ENDDATE SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL, 
    GLNUMBER VARCHAR(72) NOT NULL, 
    GLDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(24),
    primary key (IDACCOUNT, GLNUMBER, BEGINDATE, ENDDATE)
) 



--CREATE A TABLE OF DATES FOR EACH DATE IN THE PERIOD BEING EXAMINED 
DECLARE @DATES TABLE (THISDATE SMALLDATETIME) 

DECLARE @aDate SMALLDATETIME 
SELECT  @aDate = @BEGINDATE 

WHILE @aDate <= @ENDDATE 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT  @DATES(THISDATE) VALUES(@aDate) 
        SET     @aDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @aDate) 
    END 

--CREATE A TABLE THAT HAS EACH IDACCOUNT AND A CORRESPONDING ROW FOR EACH VALUE IN @DATES 
--WHERE THERE IS NO DATA IN @BASEINFO TO COVER "THISDATE"
DECLARE @GLDATES TABLE ( 
    IDACCOUNT INT, 
    THISDATE SMALLDATETIME, 
    GLNUMBER VARCHAR(72), 
    GLDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(24) 
) 

INSERT INTO @GLDATES 
SELECT  DISTINCT B.IDACCOUNT, 
        D.THISDATE, 
        B.GLNUMBER, 
        B.GLDESCRIPTION 
FROM    @BASEINFO B, 
        @DATES D 
WHERE   D.THISDATE >= 
        ( 
            SELECT  MIN(BEGINDATE) 
            FROM    @BASEINFO 
            WHERE   IDACCOUNT = B.IDACCOUNT 
                    AND GLNUMBER = B.GLNUMBER 
        ) 
        AND D.THISDATE <= 
        ( 
            SELECT  MAX(ENDDATE) 
            FROM    @BASEINFO 
            WHERE   IDACCOUNT = B.IDACCOUNT 
                    AND GLNUMBER = B.GLNUMBER 
        ) 
        AND NOT EXISTS 
        ( 
            SELECT  *   
            FROM    @BASEINFO BSI 
            WHERE   BSI.IDSACCOUNT = B.IDACCOUNT 
                    AND BSI.GLNUMBER = B.GLNUMBER 
                    AND D.THISDATE BETWEEN BSI.BEGINDATE AND BSI.ENDDATE 
        )
```

What's happening here? The goal is to find dates within the overall period where there isn't any data in @BaseInfo for that Date/IDAccount/GL.

A table variable is created to hold BaseInfo, this ultimately is the data we're interested in.  Another table variable is populated with a period of dates, usually a year, one date for each day in the period.
Create another table that's a cartesian of the two, so we have an entry for each date in @Dates and row in @BaseInfo.
Emulating the WHERE clause is what's evading me, I can create an object representative of the cartesian, but the Min/Max/Exists factors I'm hurting on.

My code so far:

```
List<GLDate> glDates =
        (
            from bai in baseAccountInformation
            from d in dateList
            select new GLDate
                   {
                       IDAccount = bai.IDAccount, 
                       ThisDate = d, 
                       GLNumber = bai.GLNumber, 
                       GLDescription = bai.GLDescription
                   }

        ).ToList();

public class GLDate
{
    public int IDAccount { get; set; }
    public DateTime ThisDate { get; set; }
    public string GLNumber { get; set; }
    public string GLDescription { get; set; }
}
```

The cross-up in handling the min/max values between the two objects is confusing me, and if the process has to get a min/max for each row and create it's own object for comparison, how efficient would that be?  I've read about all I can find on grouping and select many and am not sure how to proceed.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see where `@BASEINFO` gets populated in your SQL code. I see that it's declared but I don't see where you actually insert something into it ?

Comment: Thanks for the input, Matt.  I didn't include it because I thought it was "noise", it is populated using a basic select, I can include it if you believe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to split the inner queries from the SQL statement.
You can first retrieve the min/max/exists values by doing something like:

```
var maxEndDate = baseAccountInformation.Max(x => x.EndDate);
var minBeginDate = baseAccountInformation.Min(x => x.BeginDate);
var filter = baseAccountInformation.Where(...);
```

You can then use these values in your LINQ query in a simply where statement.
For the filter you would need to do something like `where !filter.Any(x => x == bai)`.
I hope this is clear enough.